# Managing user creation in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I need to allow users to create accounts on my wiki but I need these accounts to be inactive until an administrator has manually review them. How can I configure this behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ConfirmAccount extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aConfirmAccount) provides this functionality.